# Laravel form action sending values and id

Tags: php, laravel, routes

The submit form which allows admin to change the role of user or staff, error shows  `Missing required parameter for [Route: updateRolePermission] [URI: admin/edit-role-permission/{id}] [Missing parameter: id]` I have fighting with this issues for many hours, everyone can help thanks!!!!!

```
<form action="{{ route('updateRolePermission'), ['id' =>$user->id] }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <select name="roles">
    <option value="user">User</option>
    <option value="staff">Staff</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin', 'middleware'=>['isAdmin','auth']], function(){
    Route::get('dashboard', [AdminController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.dashboard');
    Route::get('role-permission', [AdminController::class, 'rolePermission'])->name('admin.rolePermission');

    //it doesnt work!!!!
    Route::get('edit-role-permission/{id}', [AdminController::class, 'editRolePermission'])->name('updateRolePermission');
});
```

```
    function editRolePermission($id)
    {
        $row = DB::table('users')
                ->where('id',$id)
                ->limit(1)
                ->update(array('role' => 'fdas'));

        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

Comment: Your route is `GET` method while your form is `POST` method.

Comment: `Route::get(...` should be `Route::post(...`

Comment: thanks!!, new issues, now, I can send id, but role.

Comment: There's also a typo: `route('updateRolePermission'), ['id' =>$user->id]` should be `route('updateRolePermission', ['id' =>$user->id])`. Voting to close this as a typo (both the GET/POST and the route typo)

Comment: **Don't change the question after it's solved.** If you have other issues, post a new question. I rolled back your updates. If you change it, none of the previous comments/answers will make any sense for future visitors. And if it was a specific answer that helped you solve it, accept that answer

Comment: I am very sorry for that

Comment: Did one of the below answers solve your original issue? If so, please may you mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
action="{{ route('updateRolePermission'), ['id' =>$user->id] }}"
```

to this:

```
action="{{ route('updateRolePermission', $user->id) }}"
```

Comment: Ah,...  there's a typo. They close the route before the argument. That should be pointed out in a comment and then vote to close as a typo though. So the issue isn't the array but rather that typo. This is why it's important to add an explanation to the answer to point out what the issue was, easy to miss otherwise.

Comment: In documentation, the example is `route('profile', ['id' => 1])`. you can either use the syntax in my answer, or put the `, ['id' =>$user->id]` INSIDE the parentheses .

Comment: I noticed, please read my previous comment.

Comment: I posted my comment before reading your comment, that's OK anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First your route is `GET` method while your form is `POST` method.

For the `$id`, you may get it in your controller by:

```
$id = \Route::current()->parameter('id');
```